# How can I cast an object to a string if that object may be null?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
var answer = (string)parameters[0].Value;
```

It's failing with a message:

```
Message = "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'."
```

Is there some way I can do the cast even if the Value is null and stop the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var answer = ""
if(parameters[0].Value != DBNull.Value) {
     answer = (string)parameters[0].Value
}
```

Or shorter :

```
var answer = parameters[0].Value != DBNull.Value ? (string)parameters[0].Value : ""
```

And your empty result is not null, it is DBNull.Value as your parameters seem to come from something DB-related ;)

P.S.: I don't have a visual studio by hand to test it but it should work ;)